# nginx is slower than apache when serving pdf file, anything else is faster

Tags: nginx

I have one PDF file, put it on two different servers (same hardware spec), one running Apache 2.2, the other running Nginx 1.8.0. When using IE 11, Nginx got hung, Apache went through. When using FF/Chrome, both went through but Apache is faster.

Second, I've added "pdf" into this Nginx config to force browsers to cache pdf files, but it seems, the browsers always ignore it and always download the full file every time it is accessed.

```
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|ttf|svg|eot|woff|webm|mp3|mp4|pdf|txt|xml)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
```

How to expedite pdf-file download in Nginx, and how to force the browser to cache it?

UPDATED: Response Header Nginx

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Thu, 28 May 2015 16:39:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 14709260
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 May 2015 20:35:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Etag: "55662a7f-e0720c"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Response Header Apache:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 May 2015 17:29:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6 mod_jk/1.2.26
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 May 2015 20:57:52 GMT
Etag: "196c55-e0720c-517167f19423e"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 14709260
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=85
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Comment: Slower how? Any errors in nginx error log? Suggest you post HTTP response headers for each case.